# Android in-app update shows wrong availableVersionCode (88) in AppUpdateInfo

Tags: android, in-app-update, android-update-app

I'm trying to implement an in-app update-dialog for my android app written in java.

The code snipped to check if an update is available, is taken from the [android developer page](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java). It's called in the onResume() method of the the Main activity.

```
private void checkForUpdate() {
        AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);

// Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
        Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

// Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "AppUpdateInfo: " + appUpdateInfo);
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                    // can be changed to AppUpdateType.INTERMEDIATE
                    && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
                // Request the update.
                try {
                    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                            // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
                            appUpdateInfo,
                            // Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
                            AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                            // The current activity making the update request.
                            this,
                            // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
                            APP_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

I release new app versions through the Google Play Console. There are **two closed test** tracks:

- Dev Track -> Users: Developers, Current Version: 105
- Testers Track -> Users: Testers, Current Version: 99

When printing the AppUpdateInfo into the Logcat of a developer device, the availableVersionCode is 88. At the same time the current version (105) appears in the Google Play Store.

> D/MainActivity: AppUpdateInfo: AppUpdateInfo{packageName=package.app, availableVersionCode=88, updateAvailability=1, installStatus=0, clientVersionStalenessDays=null, updatePriority=0, bytesDownloaded=0, totalBytesToDownload=0, additionalSpaceRequired=0, assetPackStorageSize=0, immediateUpdateIntent=null, flexibleUpdateIntent=null, immediateDestructiveUpdateIntent=null, flexibleDestructiveUpdateIntent=null}

There has been a version 88 in the past since the versions are incremented by 1, but currently only version 105 and 99 are live.

Now I am wondering why the AppUpdateInfo is not receiving the latest version 105.
As mentioned before, the updates are made through the Google Play Console. My guess would be, that the in-app update function receives update infos that are commited through the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher) only.

Has anyone experience the same issue and can confirm my guess?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, unforunatly I haven't found a solution. After a while the update will be available in the app too, but not immedatly.